# Right border of the edit summary field is not aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When editing a post, the right border of the **Edit Summary** field is not aligned as done for **Title**, **Body** and **Tags** fields:

> [image: Edit Summary]

Moreover, for Stack Overflow **Title** and **Rev** fields also are not aligned:

> [image: SO]

Comment: Wow. It wasn't that bad until you put a red line. Looks like those annoying OCD pictures.

Comment: I'm not sure they *should* align...

Comment: The thing that isn't aligned is the "Edit Summary" text box. I think this shows it clearer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMb0u.png

Comment: @Oded that's what the question says, your line is just in a different place ;)

Comment: @Sha why wouldn't they?

Comment: @ShadowWizard [still not sure?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIWUi.png)

Comment: @Cai dunno, maybe they didn't think to align it, just gave fixed width. But looks like it's really a bug judging by Oded's comment. :)

Comment: @Tim this is still an issue, but less obvious as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the right border of the **Rev, Title, Body, Tags** and **Edit Summary** are aligned correctly in all the Stack Exchange sites.

Screenshot taken from Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image: MSE]

Screenshot taken from Stack Overflow:

> [image: SO]

Comment: What browser are you using? I still see the [right side of tags field shifted to the left relatively edit summary field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHtJ8.png). Firefox 61.0.2 Windows 7.

Comment: Also I noticed that on your pictures font style is different for "Tags" and "Edit Summary" titles.

Comment: @alexolut Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox 62.0b19 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Style of "Edit Summary" title is changing. First time it's thin, second - bold.