# Different font size for "Edit summary" text

Tags: bug, edits, design

When you edit any question inplace, the "Edit summary" font is thin:

> [image: inplace]

But if you edit the question on the separate page (via open "edit" link on a new tab) the font is bolder:

> [image: separate]

Such weird behaviour has been found while discussing on [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291942/right-border-of-the-edit-summary-field-is-not-aligned/314569?noredirect=1#comment1030975_314569) for another bug report: [Right border of the edit summary field is not aligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291942/339911)

Answer (score 2):

Don't have same issue on MSE, but on SO yes.

If I open question for edit in new tab the text is thin, and has html:

```
<label>Edit Summary</label>
```

But if open question for edit in the same tab, html looks like this:

```
<label class="grid--cell s-label" for="edit-comment-2889777">Edit Summary</label>
```

Tested on this question: [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2889777/1991579)