# Inconsistent style for "Rev" block breaks formatting on Russian language sites

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, localization, russian-stackoverflow

[Editing a post with at least 2 revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/289456/edit) on a separate page (just open "edit" link below the post in the new window) shows the "Rev" combobox:

> [image: Rev]

The main issue here is using the word "Rev" on the same line as combobox. This looks inconsistent with the rest of the other fields like "Title", "Body" etc.

If somebody wants to change "Rev" to "Revision" it will lead to the broken design:

> [image: Revision]

Moreover, such behaviour is already observable on sites with Russian language interface like ["Stack Overflow на русском"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/):

> [image: ruSO]

<sub>click on image above to see the real edit page of the question on ruSO.</sub>

I suggest to move the "Rev" onto an individual line, this will fix the design issue on Russian interface sites, and make the page view more consistent.

> [image: result]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291942/339911